# Export C constant from lib to wrapper DLL

Tags: c, dll

I've a static C .lib file with the headers (and don't have access to the source code). I'm wrapping the .lib in a DLL for further usage. Exporting the functions works fine by converting them like such:

```
void fn_foo_ex(void) { fn_foo(); }
```

And then defining the following in a .def file:

```
fn_foo = _fn_foo_ex@0
```

The problem is the .h contains a constant like:

```
extern const int a_constant;
```

Currently I get `undefined reference` errors while linking to the DLL.
How do I 'wrap' such a constant so it appears in the DLL?

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport) int a_constant;` in your wrapper and `__declspec(dllimport) int a_constant;` in *.h

Comment: Should I change the original .h file? Will it not be a problem that the `extern const` part is then lost?

Comment: yes, need change. not a problem

Comment: The DLL does indeed compile then, but it gives me warning C4273 `inconsistent dll linkage`. Using the DLL gives an error `undefined reference to '_imp__a_constant'`

Comment: you include .h file to DLL also ? `#ifdef MY_DLL_
#define MY_DLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MY_DLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

MY_DLL_API int a_constant;`

Comment: '_imp__a_constant' mean that PE try import '_a_constant'. and your DLL must *export* it

Comment: in DLL `int a_constant` must be defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` and in exe as `__declspec(dllimport)`. the `__declspec(dllimport)` exactly produce import entry `__imp__a_const`

Comment: I think I've a slight problem here. Yes, I include the .h file in both the dll and exe. I modified it as per your last comment and the DLL compiles fine then (dependency walker shows the correct symbol being exported). I do however get the same error linking the exe. I think this is due to the fact that while compiling the DLL, the `__decl(dllexport)` version of the symbol is referenced in an inline function just below the variable declaration. So I think the DLL itself references to the `_imp_a_constant` version and it seems unable to figure out that it's the same variable it references to.

Comment: 1) build dll with `__declspec(dllexport) int a_constant` 2) make sure that LIB file created. 3) search for "__imp_a_constant" string in LIB - must be exactly this, if no - paste how `*a_constant*` is decorated 3) use this LIB as input for exe build 4) make sure that from exe view `__declspec(dllimport) int a_constant;` - if errors - what exactly ?

Comment: In .lib: `__imp__a_constant` and `_a_constant`. (Notice different underscores). I compile the exe using QT Creator and get the error:  ` undefined reference to '_imp__a_constant'`

Comment: so you *not add LIB* as linker input. `__imp__a_constant` is defined in LIB. so it will be resolved if you add LIB to linker input

Comment: I link using: LIBS += "<long path>\Release\DAPIDLL.lib". Notice that it searches for the symbol with 1 underscore less than in the lib file. Is that no problem?

Comment: `with 1 underscore less than in the lib file` - yes, this is EXACTLY a problem key point. names must be the same - symbol to symbol. this is mean that you use different definitions in DLL and EXE

Comment: must be the same count of underscore !! must be name equal because Link use `strcmp` when bind simbols

Comment: I just noticed that QT always preferred the .lib over the .dll. Explicitly specifying the DLL does not give any undefined references! So your solution does work now. If you make it an answer I can accept it.

Comment: sorry , I forget that you use x86 . really `__imp__a_constant` is correct and must be here (x86 add leader `_` to  and `cdecl` symbols ), but what is exactly unresolved symbols in exe ?

Comment: Yes, it seems it is correct indeed. When using the .dll it all works, so maybe the QT/GCC and MSVC ways of converting the symbols differ a little bit when using the .lib. The exact error when using the .lib was `undefined reference to '_imp__a_constant' `

Comment: `_imp__a_constant` but not `__imp__a_constant` ? (was confusion here by incorrect name typing, when here this is critical) - really for all imported symbols Linker add `__imp_` prefix (with 2 _ at begin) strange if `QT/GCC` work different - I not ask which environment you use - my answers was for MSVC only

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gcc/Function-Attributes.html seems to imply that GCC only uses a single _ at the beginning, but two in the middle.

Comment: need understand compiler and linker decoration - this is different. `c` compilers for `x86` (`CL`, I don't know `gcc`) add `_` to data symbols - so `a_constant` -> `_a_constant` and for `__cdecl` functions. `__stdcall` decorated as `func` -> `_func@X` (where `X=4*argc`) and `__fastcall` as `func` -> `@func@X` . `c++` symbols decorated with `?` at begin. from another side linker add `__imp_` to imported symbols. so `a_constant` is transformed to `__imp_` + `_a_constant` -> `__imp__a_constant`